# Http Request retorna un error 500 usando HttpClient pero funciona correctamente con un cliente restful

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, http, error500

estoy desarrollando una integracion con un servicio y cuando prubo el servicio mediante un cliente restful funciona correctamente. Cuando intento hacer la integracion en .NET Framework con HttpClient que hago un request al servicio este me duevule un 500 sin mucha informacion.

**ThunderClient Request:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Metodo c# usuando HttpClient:**

```
public async Task<bool> UpdateSerial(string APID, string newSerial, string orderId)
    {
        var userName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GatewayUserName"].ToString();
        var password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GatewayPassword"].ToString();
        var credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = credentials };
        
        using (var _http = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(APID) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(newSerial) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(orderId))
                throw new ArgumentException("Bad Request: Parameter Required serviceInstanceId, newSerial, orderId");
            var url = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GatewayURL"].ToString());

            var ExtraData = new List<KeyValuePair> {
                new KeyValuePair("APID", APID),
                new KeyValuePair("NEW_SERIAL", newSerial),
                new KeyValuePair("ORDER_NO", orderId)
            };
            var updateProductInstalledOTTRequest = new
            {
                extraData = ExtraData
            };
            var dataSerialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(updateProductInstalledOTTRequest);
            var objectToSend = new StringContent(dataSerialized, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            var serverResponse = await _http.PostAsync(url, objectToSend).ConfigureAwait(false);
            return serverResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode;
        }
    }
```

Error:

```
{StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1, Content: 
System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-ORACLE-DMS-ECID: 288e33c9-3bb9-4863-9aff-19556c0f80eb-0000d878
X-ORACLE-DMS-RID: 0
Date: Thu, 22 Sep 2022 14:07:02 GMT
Content-Type: application/xml
}}
```

Comment: y que sale en la depuracion paso a paso??? creo que un try catch te vendria bien ...

Comment: Esas credenciales, cuando lo haces desde el cliente restful, se las pones en el header?? si es así, prueba colocar _http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("key","valor") en vez del método que estas usando

Comment: Saludos, no tengo un try/catch porque esta esa solamente la parte de integración, manejo las excepciones en la implementación. Respondiendo a los de las credenciales las tenía así anteriormente pero me daba el mismo error. Lo que me llevo a pensar que no es por tema de autorización si no de como envío la data ya que el servicio responde con un error 500. Muchas gracias por de ante mano.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public async Task<string> TestAsync()
    {
        var respuesta = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://tu_URLDestino");
            var formData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
            formData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("APID",APID));
            formData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("NEW_SERIAL", newSerial));
            formData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ORDER_NO", orderID));
            request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(formData);
            var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                respuesta = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            else
                respuesta = response.StatusCode.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var error = ex.Message;
        }


        return respuesta;
    }
```